# How to extrapolate with these values

Tags: extrapolation

I'm reading a paper by Yallop and in it he gives the following table of values:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline x   &0.3  &0.5  &0.7   &1    &2    &3\\ \hline y    &?  & 8.4  &7.5  &6.4  &4.7  &4.3 \\\hline\end{array}$$

How do I extrapolate to find the value of $y$ when $x=0.3$?

I tried several different ways and all of them give values of $9.3$ or $ 9.4$. However the extrapolated value given by Yallop is $10.0$.

Comment: Lagrange interpolation gives $9.43$. Could you provide more information?

Comment: Could you give a link tot the paper or send it to me by e-mail (my address is in my profile).

Comment: I know.  Lagrange interpolation gives $9.4$, linear extrapolation gives $9.3$. Michael Galuza what extra information do you need?

Comment: Here is the link <astro.ukho.gov.uk/download/NAOTN69.pdf> @ClaudeLeibovici. See 3. (c), Table 3.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the data, it looks that we face an exponential function. So, using the available data points and model $$y=a\,e^{bx}+c$$ a nonlinear regression leads to $$y=8.14843\, e^{-1.25978 x}+4.08646 $$ with $R^2=0.999977$ which is very good.

Comparing to the data points, the corresponding computed values are $8.427$, $7.460$, $6.398$, $4.742$ and $4.273$.

Extrapolating the model at $x=0.3$ gives $y=9.670$.

**Edit**

Using a fit with a cubis polynomial as it seems to be done in the paper, for $x=0.3$, $y=9.502$.

Comment: That is a good fit, but to 1 d.p. it's still $9.7$, not $10.0$. The Lagrange interpolation formula give $10.0$ for $ x=2 $.